# Add Custom Lookup Fields on Activities

Tags: custom-object, activities

Is there a way how to relate custom object with activity? I can't use RelateTo field because event could (and probably will) be related to Account or Opportunity.

I heard that Salesforce will enable to add a custom lookup fields on activities. 
It was in BETA on winter 15 release. 
But there is no word about it in Spring 15 release notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest giving it a go, as salesforce is planning to release it as part of next release.

As per salesforce :

It's in open Beta for Winter '15.  You can call support to have it turned on.  It will be GA in a subsequent release.